# C# Moq method is not returning the boolean value specified

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am using the below code. I am using the same approach for other methods it's working fine. Here the adapter method of `IExportJobAdapter`  which has been mocked should return Task of boolean type value.

From the code I am expecting to get the true value but I am getting false from my mock method. Inside the controller I have called the mocked method of `IExportJobAadapter` which is returning false. I have tried many things from stack overflow but not able to resolve. I would like to repeat that this is happening only in case of returning bool method. All other places I am using the same approach and its working fine.

```
var controller = mocker.CreateInstance<ExportJobController>();
```

Mocked adapter method

```
mocker.GetMock<IExportJobAdapter>()
    .Setup(x => x.CreateExportJob(null))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

// Act
var result = await controller.CreateExportJob(new ExportJobRequest { ProfileId = profileId, Request = request,DttmCreated= dttmCreated });
```

Comment: Need to see the code under test.

Comment: Most likely the argument passed to the mock does not match when the test is exercised.

Comment: Post missing [MCVE]… but as @Nkosi said it most likely due to `x.CreateExportJob(null)` (setting up method to return particular value when called with `null`) and not usual `x.CreateExportJob(It.IsAny<ExportJobRequest>())`

Comment: Thanks a lot Nkosi and Alexei . I tried with x.CreateExportJob(It.IsAny<ExportJobRequest>()) and its working perfectly.

Comment: @sks I added a link in the provided answer below. to the quick start documentation. You should take some time and give it a read to get a better understanding of how Moq works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Setup method in your mock does not have the same parameters as the code you are testing then the mock will not match the call and you will get the default value for the expected response, in this case the default value for a boolean is `false` - which is what you are seeing.

If you want the mock to return the specified value then you need to tell Setup to accept any value for the parameter:

```
mocker.GetMock<IExportJobAdapter>()
    .Setup(x => x.CreateExportJob(It.IsAny<ExportJobRequest>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
```

In your example I have assumed that the method `CreateExportJob` takes a parameter of `ExportJobRequest`. So when the above mock is called, it will ignore what is passed as the parameter to `CreateExportJob` and return `true`.

In addition to that, you can use the `.ReturnsAsync` method of the mock to remove the need to call `Task.FromResult`:

```
mocker.GetMock<IExportJobAdapter>()
    .Setup(x => x.CreateExportJob(It.IsAny<ExportJobRequest>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for more about how to use the mocking library.

Comment: +1 to this answer. This is a good reason to inject object provider and creators and avoid "new" keyword if you want to really make sure the right parameter is passed.